# scipy installation error for windows 64 bit

Tags: scipy

I am trying to install scipy on windows -8.1 64 bit but I am getting an error:

> Failed to building wheel for scipy

and

> Failed to cleaning dir build for scipy

Can anyone try to help me? what is wrong?

Comment: Please also indicate python and scipy versions you use and how you tried to install it

Comment: python-3.5,scipy-0.19.0,as pip install scipy-was the command used

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the normal python distribution? There are issues installing scipy as other dependencies are required, which may not be available readily for Windows.

Unless there is any specific reason for going for the standard python distribution, I would recommend that you download [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It ensures a working Windows build for numpy, scipy, etc., which are normally used by data scientists.